# JavaScript: how to include a file in a way that will work either on node.js and on the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

I am writting a file that is going to be usable either in the browser and on node.js. To use a library, I could import it using `_ = require('underscore.js'); main();` on node, and `$.getScript('underscore.js',function(){ main(); });` on the browser. What is the right way to include a file that will work on both environments?

Answer (score 3):

You could use an AMD compliant module loader such as RequireJS.

http://requirejs.org/

Comment: Could you detail exactly how you use RequireJS for having the same include code that works for both environments?

Comment: @Dokkat It is all in the require.js documentation. Check the website for usage examples etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try [object detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html):

```
if($ && $.getScript){
    $.getScript('underscore.js',function(){ main(); });
}else if(require){
    _ = require('underscore.js');
}else{
    /* output: Could not load library 'underscore.js'. */
}
```

A danger with this is that `require` may be defined but means something else.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but I thought it was a little undelicate.

Comment: dqhendricks' suggestion is probably better, I saw it appear just as I posted this. (:

Comment: I hate require.js's documentation, through.